# Entity Framework SQL connection issue after migration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been tasked with migrating an application from IIS 6/SQL Server 8 to IIS 8/SQL Server 2008 R2. I can run the application from VS2012 on my local machine and connect to a local instance of SQL 2008 R2, but I'm getting the following on the new server:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I didn't build this application, so I'm a little blind here, but here is the connection string:

```
<add name="CensusEntities"      
            connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CensusModel.csdl|res://*/Models.CensusModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.CensusModel.msl;
            provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=STARGATE\DWCREPORTS;
            Initial Catalog=Census;Persist Security Info=False;
            user id=***;password=***;
            multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'" 
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Here is the Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +970
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +802
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +682
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +141
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +362    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +41
>
> [EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +206
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +104
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +75
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +41
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   +36    System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +109    System.Data.Objects.ELinq.<>c__11`1.<GetElementFunction>b__11_1(IEnumerable`1
>   sequence) +41
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot) +59
>
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +134
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +60    System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +249
>
>   CustomMembershipProvider.GetDBUser(CensusEntities db, String username)
>   in
>   c:\APPLICATIONS\DEVELOPMENT\PastoralReports\Models\CustomMembershipProvider.cs:317
>   CustomMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String
>   password) in
>   c:\APPLICATIONS\DEVELOPMENT\PastoralReports\Models\CustomMembershipProvider.cs:469
>   System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String
>   password) +26    Census.Controllers.RootController.LogOn(LogOnModel
>   model, String returnUrl) in
>   c:\APPLICATIONS\DEVELOPMENT\PastoralReports\Controllers\RootController.cs:28
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +194
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
>   +58    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +99    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +16    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +16    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +25
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +16    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9744261    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Are you sure you are not copying your local Web.config version on the Server?

Comment: Can you connect to the database from within SQL Server Management Studio on your local machine using the credentials in the web.config? This error usually means either the server and/or database don't exist or you are not allowed to access it.